# Conditional DynamoDB put item in lambda (python)

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-dynamodb, conditional-statements

How do I put an item in a dynamodb table only if that item does not exist. So far, I have:

```
table.put_item(
   Item:={
       'greeting': 'hi'
   },
   ConditionExpression= 'attribute_not_exists(hi)'
)
```

What would my condition expression be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this:

```
ConditionExpression= "attribute_not_exists(Id)" // where id is your unique key
```

Comment: I just edited my question, however it is still not working. The item keeps getting overwritten,

Comment: You should replace `hi` in `attribute_not_exists` to the name of your partition key attribute e.g. `attribute_not_exists(greeting)` assuming "greeting" is the name of the partition key

Comment: You can catch the error with `ClientError` defined in the Boto3 SDK ([See how](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/error-handling.html)), then add your error handling logic.